# Support regarding Android WebView SSL trust

Tags: android, ssl, webview, webviewclient

I need help regarding SSL trust. I am loading a payment gateway page in WebView. It is a POST request and I am passing a payload.
This is happening successfully till now.(Shown below)

```
mWebView = (Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;

string payload = "myPayload";

byte[] valTest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.ToCharArray(0, payload.Length));

mWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
mWebView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled=true;

mWebView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
mWebView.SetWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
mWebView.PostUrl("https://mypage", valTest);
```

After filling up the form and submit I am getting a callback in the OnReceivedSslError method of the WebViewClient class. Here I ask it to proceed (as per various forums). Once this is done I am not getting any success callback. I need to be able to read javascript values once I get a response from the webview. I do not know how this is to be achieved.
Shown below is the OnSSLErrorReceived Callback method.

```
public override void OnReceivedSslError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, Android.Net.Http.SslError error)
        {
                base.OnReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                handler.Proceed();
                           }
        }
```

Expectations-
1.  On submitting the form it should be trusted(it is a self-signed certificate).
2.  Once this above step is done we are expecting a response from the webpage. We need to read javascript values from the page. How can I achieve this?
I do not see any SuccessCallback or ResponseCallback.

I use the below to read the JS values.But this is not working.

```
 view.EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('test').value", new MyCallbackClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

The above issue has been resolved. Calling handler.Proceed in OnSSLError method was fine but the issue was with calling the base inside this callback. Once I removed base.OnSSLError my code worked fine.

After the page finishes I am able to read JS values in the OnPageFinished callback method.
Also the evaluate JS function is also working and I get callbacks.

Comment: In my case the onReceivedSSLError method is not getting called instead onReceivedErrror is getting called